# Do PHP threads run sequentially?

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I did all the work to custom build php with pthread support. I slightly edited this code from: http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

```
class workerThread extends Thread {
public function __construct($i){
  $this->i=$i;
  $this->c=0;
}

public function run(){
while($this->c < 10){
   echo $this->i , '<br/>';
   sleep(1);
   $this->c++;
}
}
}

for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
$workers[$i]=new workerThread($i);
$workers[$i]->start();
}
```

The output is not as i would have expected where all results are in sequential order: 0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3 etc.

Do I misunderstand how threads should work? Isn't the sleep(1) supposed to allow another thread to take control of the processor and perform it's calculation?

Comment: Try call flush() after echo.

Answer (score 0):

No, the threads created by PHP's pthreads extension do not run sequentially. They are actual kernel threads, and so they will run however the task scheduler of the kernel decides to run them.

> Isn't the sleep(1) supposed to allow another thread to take control of the processor and perform it's calculation?

Given the `sleep()` function in PHP utilises the sleep system call, the following description [from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_(system_call)#Low_level_functionality) is applicable:

> Sleep causes the thread or process to give up the remainder of its time slice and stay in the Not Runnable state for the specified duration. While there is generally a guarantee for the minimum time period, there is no strict guarantee that the thread will run immediately or soon, or even at all, once the specified time has passed. It is up to the scheduler's discretion, and dependent on thread priorities and implementation details such as timer resolutions when the sleeping thread will run again.